Scale an image to fully cover the viewports width and height but leave it uncut and add scrollbars
I want to scale an image proportionally so that one dimension is 100% of the viewport and the other is larger than the viewport but leave it uncropped and instead add scroll bars in the larger direction. It needs to work for images with different aspect ratios and with different aspect ratios of the viewport.
See this drawing (black is viewport, gray is image)
I have tried setting min-width: 100vw and min-height: 100vh. This works when the viewport is larger than the image's pixel dimensions but not when it is smaller. (The image in the code is 600x400px. Run code snippet in full page and drag the browser window smaller than 600px wide and 400px high to see that the scaling of the image then does not match the viewport.)
I have also tried background-image but then the image is cropped with no scroll bars.
Since the code almost works, there should be an easy fix or do I need to solve it some other way?


html {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
}
.full-plus {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
}
.full-plus img {
 min-width: 100vw;
 min-height: 100vh;
}
<html>
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="full-plus">
   <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
 </body>
</html>




I suspect you will need a couple of lines of Javascript for this as (at least, currently) we can't do calcs dividing one united value by another united value in CSS. Alternatively, do you know the aspect ratio of the image in advance (so could build it into the CSS)?

It needs to work on images with different aspect ratios. So frustrating that the code above works on images that are smaller but not larger than the browser window. Do you have a suggestion for a Javascript solution? Thanks!

Just to clarify - the questionnasks how to make the shortest side of the image take up the whole of 100vw or 100vh as relevant. Doesn't the aspect ratio of the viewport come into this at all? For example, if the viewport has aspect-ratio 4 / 2 and the image has aspect ratio 3 / 2, making the image height 100vh will mean it completely sits inside the viewport because the width will be (3/2 * 100vh) which is (3/2 * 2/4 * 100vw) which is 75vw. i.e. no scrolling.

If the image is 3/2 and the viewport is 4/2 the image should be 100vw and 133vh with vertical scrollbars. Take a look at the drawing in the link above for clarification. You find it at this url: https://jenstarning.se/full-plus.jpg

Sorry @AHaworth , I just saw that the title was misleading. I have changed it now.

OK, thanks, that makes it clearer. I still think you'll need some JS which can work out what the relative aspect-ratios of the viewport and the image are.

Thank you! Do you have a suggestion for a Javascript solution?


It needs to work on images with different aspect ratios.

@AHaworth is right - you'll need JS here to:

inspect and compare the original dimensions of the image
inspect and compare the dimensions of the viewport


Working Example:
(Toggle to Full Page to see the effect...)


const bgImage = document.querySelector('.bgImage');

const resizeDiv = () => {
  
  const imageDimensions = {
    width: bgImage.naturalWidth,
    height: bgImage.naturalHeight
  }

  if ((imageDimensions.width / imageDimensions.height) < (window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight)) {
    bgImage.style.setProperty('width', '100vw');
    bgImage.style.setProperty('height', 'auto');
  } else {
    bgImage.style.setProperty('width', 'auto');
    bgImage.style.setProperty('height', '100vh');
  } 
}

window.addEventListener('resize', resizeDiv);

resizeDiv();
body {
 margin: 0;
}

.bgImage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
}
<div>
  <img class="bgImage" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" alt="Northern Lights" />
</div>




Thanks Rounin, but I am looking for a solution where the user can scroll sideways or down to see the rest of the image.

Thanks for clarification, @Jens - as i was finishing my post I realised this might actually not be the effect you're trying to achieve.

Thanks anyway! It is so frustrating not to find a solution when my code works on images that are smaller in their pixel dimensions than the view port but not larger. Thought it would be a simple problem to solve.

Thanks for the updated solution! BUT... I want the image to fill the entire browser window and remain uncut with scrollbars. See this drawing for clarification. https://jenstarning.se/full-plus.jpg Sorry if I was unclear.

@Jens - this took a few abortive attempts, but I'm pretty sure I've cracked it, now.

You definitely cracked it! Great work! I hadn't solved this myself so worth a lot to me. Thank you so much @Rounin!!
